# How to force Bootstrap font style on element

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a site that I have restyled with Bootstrap 5 and am having an issue with a few elements that get their styles from other stylesheets and I'm trying to figure out how to override those styles and apply the Bootstrap font stack.
I could just apply a font-family style to the elements needed but want to have the whole bootstrap stack apply.
If there is no way to do this, is there a way to reference the built in bootstrap fonts individually? ie: font-family: "Helvetica Neue".
I did some googling but everything comes up as how to override the default bootstrap font which is kind of the opposite of what I want.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Bootstrap CSS Variable](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/css-variables/#root-variables): `--bs-body-font-family`. This way you are not repeating code and, you don't have to update your styles if you decide to customize and recompile Bootstrap.

```css
/* custom.css */

.custom {
  font-family: serif;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

<p>This is a plain <code>p</code> tag with no class.</p>

<p class="custom">
  This <code>p.custom</code> is rendered with <code>font-family: serif</code> from the external custom.css stylesheet.
</p>

<p class="custom" style="font-family: var(--bs-body-font-family);">
  This <code>p.custom</code> is rendered with <code>font-family: var(--bs-body-font-family)</code> from the style property. This could also be applied in an embedded stylesheet, or an additional external stylesheet loaded after bootstrap.css, which should
  be loaded before custom.css.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for how to do this, I was able to do this using the font-family as needed;

```css
font-family: 
system-ui,
/* // Safari for macOS and iOS (San Francisco) */
-apple-system,
/* // Windows */
"Segoe UI",
/* // Android */
Roboto,
/* // Basic web fallback */
"Helvetica Neue", Arial,
/* // Linux */
"Noto Sans",
"Liberation Sans",
/* // Sans serif fallback */
sans-serif;
```

Comment: So you chose to have 2 primary fonts, "Noto Sans" and "Liberation Sans" all in Linux, and the rest are fallbacks?  Why 2 primary for Linux?  I understand "Segoe UI" is for when in Windows.

Comment: I just took the style from the default bootstrap stack;
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/reboot/#native-font-stack